# Leaflet; linking text to geometries

Tags: leaflet

How to connect a text in the website to a polygon on leaflet map?
(I am not refering to labeling - a simple html text)
Or a more advanced option: how to highlight this polygon when mouse is over the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For highlighting text in website and polygons on leaflet map, here I have a working simple example for you. It uses jQuery and LeafletJS from CDN's so you can just copy this to one file and save it as `.html`.

To fire an action on mouse over text I use jQuery id selector with the `.hover()` function. Then I use `.setStyle()` function to change polygons `fillOpacity` property. Of course you can use other functions (e.g. `.animate()`) and change different properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div><p>This is <strong><span id="text1">red polygon, actually a circle</span></strong> and this is <strong><span id="text2">blue polygon</span></strong> to test hover and hightlight.</p>

    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>

        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(map);

        var polygon1 = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: '#f03',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a circle.");

        var polygon2 = L.polygon([
            [51.509, -0.08],
            [51.503, -0.06],
            [51.51, -0.047]
        ]).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");

        var popup = L.popup();

        $('#text1').hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background","red");
            polygon1.setStyle({fillOpacity: 1});
        },function(){
            $(this).css("background","");
            polygon1.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.5});
        });

        $('#text2').hover(function() {
            $(this).css("background","blue");
            polygon2.setStyle({fillOpacity: 1});
        },function(){
            $(this).css("background","");
            polygon2.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.5});
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And here is this example to play around in **codepen.io**:
http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/jyeyry

Comment: Thank you! It's working perfect. Just one thing: isn't there an option without the plugin: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"

Comment: Sure you can do it without jQuery and use just simple javascript, example in new codepen here: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/BpqdZm

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the [Story Map plugin](https://github.com/JackDougherty/leaflet-storymap).  Like the answer from d324223 it is also based on JQuery but wrapped as a neat plugin for leaflet.

for other ideas see [this page](https://schoolofdata.org/2014/08/25/seven-ways-to-create-a-storymap/) on how to create a story map.

Comment: Quite impressive examples, thanks.      Out of topic but, is of my interest how can one create a timeline like in http://revolt.axismaps.com/map/